# (0, _File.Function) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using React Native and am trying to give a Component access to a client while keeping it in a separate file. The code for that is:

```
export default function SearchFactory(restClient){
    return class Search extends Component {
        // regular component stuff, that references restClient
    }
}
```

When I try to access it in App.js, with the import being `import {SearchFactory} from './screens/SearchFactory';`

and the code being const `SearchView = SearchFactory(restClient);`, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: (0, SearchFactory.SearchFactory) is not a function. (In '(0, SearchFactory.SearchFactory)(restClient)', '(0, SearchFactory.SearchFactory)' is undefined)
```

I have tried removing the client input, but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are importing the `default` export of a module you want to skip the surrounding `{}` that you use for named exports.

```js
import SearchFactory from './screens/SearchFactory';
```